# MySQL BIT Variable Type Altering Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns and two variable types.

CATEGORY VARCHAR(64)

HASH BIT(49)

I'm using a php page to insert new values each time they are found.

Here is an example insertion statement:

```
INSERT INTO `HASH` (HASH, CATEGORY) VALUES (0b1001010010110101011100111000101000010100001110001, 'foo');
```

The query executes fine, but here's the problem.

Now, when I look in my database, the 'foo' hash value is this:

```
1001100100011011100110000001100010011010000110000
```

When the original value was:

```
1001010010110101011100111000101000010100001110001
```

Why is this?  And how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you count your digits? I did. There are 50.

Comment: There are 49.  It seems to be working despite the accuracy problem.  I'm not sure why, but it should be okay.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error must be located somewhere else.

The code works. See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/979b41/2).

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be working, maybe it is an error in PHPMYADMIN that's showing an incorrect values?  I need to compute the hemming distance between a computed hash and a stored has, and it seems to be working despite the values differing in the database.  Thanks for the help!